# Editing custom group settings

Tags: custom-fields

I'm trying to edit the settings for an existing custom fields group. When I make the changes and save it, I get this:

`Please correct the following errors in the form fields below:`

`Custom group 'Training Information' already exists in Database.`

Answer (score 0):

Quick guess. Did you double click the save button?

Or, it's suggesting there's already a "Training Information" Dataset on your system. Maybe for a different entity type e.g activity data not contact data.

Comment: Nope, just a single click. The only one called that is this one - it's been there for years. I just needed to make a quick edit on the settings for that group (not be collapsed).